# Where do we get the prior for Maximum a Posteriori Estimation

Tags: probability-distributions, machine-learning

I'm reading the book "Mathematics for Machine Learning", it's a free book that you can find [here](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf). The section 8.3.2 is about Maximum A Posteriori Estimation (or MAP).

What I understood about MAP is that it is similar to `maximum likelihood estimation`. In the context of MLE we have probability distribution $p(x|\theta)$ which shows us how likely data $x$ is to be generated by model with parameters $\theta$. In context of MAP we are inverting the distribution $p(x|\theta)$ using Bayes' rule (which I simplified):
$$p(\theta|x) \propto p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$$

Point is that instead of asking how likely data $x$ is to be generated by model with parameters $\theta$ (which is captured by $p(x|\theta)$) we're asking how likely model with parameters $\theta$ will generate our data $x$ (which is captured by $p(\theta|x)$).

However to find $p(\theta|x)$ we have to know $p(\theta)$, which is a prior knowledge about parameters $\theta$. What I don't understand is, in a context of machine learning, were do we get this prior knowledge about model parameters? What does $p(\theta)$ even mean, probability distribution of model parameters? What does it mean to have a probability distribution of parameters?

Comment: $p(\theta)$ is a [prior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) for knowledge or belief about the parameters, and is needed for Bayesian analysis to be updated by observations to give a posterior distribution.  It is just a distribution which obeys Kolmogorov's axioms, but can be seen a distribution of belief rather than a narrow sense of probability. There are various approaches, including the use of conjugate priors to ease calculations, or some form of informed or uninformed prior depending on your starting point, and the need to remember Cromwell's rule.

Comment: @Henry Yes, but how do we get the prior? If for example I have a dataset of vectors $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and a linear model $x_n^T\theta$ and I don't know the parameters $\theta$ how do I get the $p(\theta)$? If I don't know what parameters $\theta$ are how do I get a distribution of those parameters?

Comment: The prior should come from those commissioning the model: Bayesian analysis is about updating their beliefs in the light of the observations, so their prior belief should not depend on the observations.

Comment: Alright, can you give me an example?

Comment: OK: suppose you have a coin you believe is slightly biased but you do not know how much or in which direction, but you are willing to say your belief that the probability $p$ of Heads has a prior Beta$(6,6)$ distribution so a roughly $50\%$  degree of belief that $0.4<p<0.6$.  You then flip it $20$ times and see $12$ heads and $8$ tails.  This leads you to a posterior distribution for $p$ which is Beta$(18,14)$, which has a mode of about $0.5667$ and a mean of $0.5625$ and a roughly $50\%$  degree of belief that $0.50 < p < 0.62$.  You have updated your prior with the observations.

Comment: Compare that to a maximum likelihood estimate of $\hat p=\frac{12}{12+8} = 0.6$.  That takes no account of your prior belief that the bias was probably slight.  The distribution of values $p$ might actually take is hard to decide as likelihood does not give a probability distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations! However I still don't know how to apply them to machine learning but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example can be found in pages 363-366 (section 11.4) of your book.

Assume we have a Gaussian mixture model (GMM). Assume *K* components and each data point can be generated by exactly one mixture component. Introduce a binary variable $z_k\in\{0,1\}$ for whether the *k*th mixture component generated the data point so that $p(\textbf x|z_k=1)=\mathcal N(\textbf x|\mu_k, \Sigma _k)$.

Assume the indicators are unknown and place a *prior distribution* on them: $p(\textbf z)=\pi=(\pi_1,\dots,\pi_k)$.

Then the *posterior distribution* can be obtained using Bayes rule:

$$p(z_k=1|\textbf x)=\frac{p(z_k=1)p(\textbf x|z_k=1)}{p(\textbf x)}=\frac{p(z_k=1)p(\textbf x|z_k=1)}{\sum _{j=1}^Kp(z_j=1)p(\textbf x|z_j=1)}=\frac{\pi_k\mathcal N(\textbf x|\mu_k, \Sigma _k)}{\sum _{j=1}^K\pi_j\mathcal N(\textbf x|\mu_j, \Sigma _j)}$$

Example:

Assume we have a mixture of three normal distributions with initial probability vector $(\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3)=(.3, .4, .3)$. These correspond to the initial probabilities that we think the mixture components would be drawn from. Assume mixture component one is $\mathcal N(0, 1)$, second is $\mathcal N(5, 2)$, third is $\mathcal N(-3, 1)$. Assume we observe a data point $x=2$. (Note this is a one-dimensional example.)

What would our posterior distribution $(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3|x=2)$ be in light of the observation. I calculate:

$p(x)=.3\mathcal N(2|0, 1)+.4\mathcal N(2|5, 2)+.3\mathcal N(2|-3, 1)=0.02809076$. This will be the denominator in the calculations.

$p(z_1=1|x=2)=\frac{.3\mathcal N(2|0, 1)}{0.02809076}=.58$

$p(z_1=2|x=2)=\frac{.4\mathcal N(2|5, 2)}{0.02809076}=.42$

$p(z_1=3|x=2)=\frac{.3\mathcal N(2|-3, 1)}{0.02809076}=.000016$

Thus, our posterior belief is $(\pi|x=2)=(.58, .42, .000016)$ and if we were to use something like MAP we would pick that it came from mixture component 1.

Something similar to this is a Hidden Markov Model where the states are not independent of each other but depend on the previous state.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot (again)! So basically I don't have to worry about it yet because I will find answers in the later chapters of the book.

Comment: @acmpo6ou i personally made the example though. haha

Comment: Oh, wow, then I have a question: in you example we have an initial probability vector, where do we get it from?

Comment: Wait, I'm reading the next chapter of the book and in section 9.2 they explain MAP more closely. And from what I understood, thinking about the prior distribution as a prior knowledge is a bit misleading (at least in the context of ML). It's better to think about it as a regularization, so we just have to find the prior that will best regularize our model. So basically we have to try out different priors and see what will best work for us.

Comment: @acmpo6ou maybe so. i am not too familiar with the term "regularization", but it's true that if the number of data points is large then the choice of prior distribution will not affect the posterior distribution much \\ really, I don't know, I just made it up. (.3, .4, .3) is close to assuming no knowledge (assuming the mixture components are equally likely)

Comment: So that's the problem, you guys are more focused on math then on math for machine learning. I was expecting more of a machine learning focused example. I guess it's better for me to ask questions on another forum: datascience.stackexchange.com